# Setting height and width of an inline element

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons (display set to inline) with height and width set for them.
I was under the impression that you can only set height and width of block or inline-block elements.
Why does it still allow me to set the height and width of inline elements if that's the case?

example [here](https://codepen.io/psj01/pen/oQgRVq).

```css
input {
  display: inline;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me">
<input type="button" value="click me2">
```

Comment: Actually, `width` will work, but `height` will not.

Comment: The computed value is inline-block according to Chrome

Comment: @BenM both width and height does work.... I'm just wondering why it works... I've lean that width and height only works for block elements. for inline its ignored... but that doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: The code works fine...

Comment: @psj01 No, the `height` property is being ignored. The buttons in your snippet are actually `18px` tall, not `50px`.

Comment: @Alexander the code works fine.. I'm just trying to understand why it works.. even though i've set display to inline.

Comment: @BenM When I use chrome inspect they are indeed 50px and display:inline. As OP is saying his code is working

Comment: @BenM I opened up the developer tools in chrome and inspected one of the buttons.. it says height:50px and display:inline..

Comment: @LucasWieloch  No, check the physical dimensions: https://imgur.com/a/1gVb35x (Chrome 69 on a Mac).

Comment: @BenM thats weird.. the image you show is different from what I see.

Comment: @BenM see https://imgur.com/a/BC9i9fB.

Comment: @psj01 you are simply using an other Browser then BenM.

Comment: @J.Sadi i'm using chrome (version 70) on windows.

Comment: another intresting point is that button can be transformed ... like described in the duplicate, the key word is **inline replaced element**

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Except that `<button>` does not meet the criteria for a replaced element, either according to CSS 2.2, or HTML5, since its *contents* are clearly styleable by CSS. Buttons are just weird, since from a [`display-outside`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#typedef-display-outside) perspective they do indeed behave just like replaced elements, but from a `display-inside` perspective they are [subject to CSS styling](https://jsbin.com/nocedoveci/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

"It works" isn't a completely a true statement. I don't see height represented in the pen you provided using Chrome 69 on the Mac.

That said, I know that some browsers will respect height sometimes (frequently on special items like form elements), try your example with a `span`. That's not a failing of either CSS or the browser.

`Display` values are intended to predict how the element interacts with other's around it not specifically the display of the element itself. Block elements are intended to take up more vertical space than text `line-height` so the spec is more intentional about how those elements deal with heights.

As for why "it" (I assume you mean your editor) allows you to add a height to inline elements, that's a feature of HTML & CSS. You can add anything you want as long as its properly formed. Then it's up to the browser to render or ignore it based on how the render engine interprets the spec.

Comment: not sure if this is relevant ... the issue we are facing will only apply to button because they are somehow *special* element and browser handle them differently

Comment: when I inspect the element this is what I see.. it does say inline and the height and width is also set. https://imgur.com/a/BC9i9fB